# UserClaimsPrincipalFactory not working in Blazor WebAssembly 3.1 (client)?

Tags: blazor, claims-based-identity, webassembly

I have built a component following the guide(s) here:

[How To Extend ASP.NET Core 3.0 And 3.1 Identity User](https://www.reflections-ibs.com/blog/articles/how-to-extend-asp-net-core-3-0-and-3-1-identity-user)

[How to extend ASP.NET Core Identity user](https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/identity/extend-user-model.html)

I have also tried IClaimsTransformation and IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory options to no avail on Blazor WebAssembly ...

Does anyone have this working ?

Thanks

Comment: All those Links (and APIs) are for server-side code.  What good is Identity in a Wasm app?  The key parts are likely not targetting standard2.0.  Use a JWT and the whole signing and validation stuff becomes off-the-shelve.

Comment: Is that help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 ?

Comment: The JWT Claims are not mapping correctly to the user object, so roles are "role" not a proper schema definition.

Comment: @Grant I face the same problem. Any solution yet ?

Comment: I've made a github repo and got this working for Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0. / .NET & EF 5 Preview - Multiple Roles and Additional User Claims

See: https://github.com/JeepNL/Blazor-WASM-Identity-gRPC

Comment: @Jaap, Thanks to you I got this working, when using default IS4 plumbing.  I have now tried to bypass the scaffolded UI and just send ID and PW from Blazor Client to custom API which calls SignInManager.  I can see claims being built by my custom UserClaimPrincipalFactory, but they are not making it back to the client.  Your code had previously fixed this, but now I'm going straight from client via API to SignInManager, the claims are no longer available in client.  Have you come across anything in your travels that might indicate why?

Comment: @NeilW I'm sorry, I've not but you're doing something I want to do as well. For my next project(s) I do not want to use Identity Server 4 anymore because there will be no more free updates. This is actually on the top of my list of thing I want to research/learn, but I haven't had the time so far.

Comment: @Jaap.  Thanks for the response.  FYI, I have now got to the point of:  1) From my Index, Login links to another client razor page.  2) From that login page I can call my own API, which in turn calls SignInManager.  3) When client get a +ve response it redirectors to "/dashboard" (another client razor page), BUT additional claims are not available.  4) I hit refresh and then the claims are available.  I guess that's something to with the blazor routing engine not going back to server for "/dashboard" (and retrieving token).

Comment: @Jaap It looks like the info in parts 2 and 3 of this link is what you're (we're) looking for!  https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/ ... Cloned his GIT repo and was able to (1) Use Client Page calling Web API to retrieve JWT.  (2) Add custom claims to the token on the server in LoginController.Login.  (3) Access those custom claims 1st time of asking in the client.  (4) No sign of Identity Server 4.  I am yet to integrate with my own project, but unless there's a hidden gotcha, I think it will do the trick.

Comment: @neilw You know that when you add (e.g. as an admin in the client) a claim/role you'll need to log out and log in again for that claim to be available in the client? At least, I think this is how it works. And yes, that article from Chris is great, I've bookmarked it.

Comment: @Jaap Sure.  I was not adding claims in the client, which may require a login / logout to refresh.  I had been having a problem where the first login did not return all claims from the server (which is what your code had originally held me fix).  Under the new NoIS4 solution I have, and with help of Chris's article, I have now been able to get those claims after initial login (without needed an additional Http request).

Comment: @Jaap I have now integrated the NoIS4 approach into my main project.  There were some snags around use of "BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler" and attaching tokens for calls from strongly-typed API clients, but have got round those and after a quick test of where I'd anticipated pain points, it looks like I'm now free of IS4 and have API and SignalR Authentication and Authorization working fine.  Feel free to reach out if any of my experience with this transition can help you with your own efforts.

Comment: @neilw Okay, I'll do that (reach out if I need help) thank you for your replies.